# Indentation for Nomenclature in ToC in Book class

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis, nomenclature, nomencl, book-class

[image]

I am writing a dissertation and want to use nomenclature. I would like to align the nomenclature entry in ToC with (Dedication, preface, etc ). Here my MWE. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=1.05,sups,lf]{XCharter} %Document body font
\usepackage[margin= 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Dedication}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{} Dedication}
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{} Preface}
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{} Acknowledgement}
\chapter*{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{} Summary}

\tableofcontents
\printnomenclature[2.5 cm]
\listoffigures 
\listoftables  

\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{one}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Two}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{one}
\section{Two}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{one}
\section{Two}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the default alignment of your unnumbered chapters so do the same for nomenclature.

```
\usepackage%[intoc]
  {nomencl}
...
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{} Nomenclature}
\printnomenclature[2.5cm]
\listoffigures
...
```

Make sure that the `\addcontentsline` and `\printnomenclature` will be on the same page

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. Cheers.